# Dribbble API access_token expiration timeout

Tags: timeout, access-token

I am trying to figure out if there is any expiration / timeout associated with an access_token generated by dribbble API.

I have followed the [API docs](https://developer.dribbble.com/v2/oauth/) to generate access_token via calling

```
https://dribbble.com/oauth/token?client_id=CLIENT_ID&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET&code=COPIED_CODE
```

...and received (code copied from API docs)

```json
{
  "access_token" : "29ed478ab86c07f1c069b1af76088f7431396b7c4a2523d06911345da82224a0",
  "token_type" : "bearer",
  "scope" : "public upload"
}
```

Now, having an `access_token`, how safe is it to use in production? Is there any expiration timeout for this `access_token` or is it lifetime until explicitly revoked?